# Grouping by first column

Tags: text-processing

Have a file with below pattern

```
a 12
a 13
a 15
a 14
b 5
b 6
c 2
c 5
```

I'd like to group these according to the first column, like below

```
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that the data is sorted by the first column, as it is in the question, using GNU `datamash` to group by the first whitespace-delimited column and collapse the second.

```bash
$ datamash -W groupby 1 collapse 2 <file
a       12,13,15,14
b       5,6
c       2,5
```

Replacing the tab after the first column in the result as well as the commas, by spaces, to arrive at the wanted output:

```bash
$ datamash -W groupby 1 collapse 2 <file | tr '\t,' '  '
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

If the input is not sorted by the first column, then pass the data through `sort` first, or use `datamash` with its `-s` (`--sort`) option.

---

You may also use [Miller (`mlr`)](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and its [`nest`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/index.html#nest) operation.  Using this, you can "implode" the values in the second column into space-delimited lists for each unique value in the first column:

```bash
$ mlr --nidx nest --implode --values --across-records --nested-fs space -f 2 file
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

Or, using the `--ivar` shorthand with miller version 5.5.0 or newer (except in 6.0.0 where it was [broken](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/936)):

```bash
$ mlr --nidx nest --ivar space -f 2 file
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

The data is not required to be pre-sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk` (if the input file is sorted by the first column):

```
awk '{ printf "%s", (NR==1 || pre!=$1? (NR>1? ORS:"")$1: "") OFS $2; pre=$1 }
END  { print "" }' infile
```

Using `awk` +`sort` (if the input file is not sorted by the first column):

```
<infile sort|
    awk '{ printf "%s", (NR==1 || pre!=$1? (NR>1? ORS:"")$1: "") OFS $2; pre=$1 }
    END  { print "" }'
```

Or using only `awk` either for sorted input or unsorted:

```
awk '{ grp[$1]= (grp[$1]==""?"":grp[$1] OFS) $2 }
END  { for(x in grp) print x, grp[x] }' infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'lines.map(*.words).map(*.hash).classify( *.keys, :as{$_.values} ).put;'
```

Sample Input:

```
a 12
a 13
a 15
a 14
b 5
b 6
c 2
c 5
```

Sample Output:

```
a   12 13 15 14
b   5 6
c   2 5
```

Here are solutions coded in **Raku**, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The above code handles the (simple) case of a two-column list (explanation of more general solution, below).

For a more general solution (with two-or-more column input), read `lines` linewise, breaking elements in `words`, and `append` into a `%h` hash, using the `=>` (fat-arrow) hash constructor to delineate keys (left) and values (right). Note, the special `.=` assignment operator saves us the step of declaring `my %h;` separately and first. Then `classify` the `%h` hash by `key`, taking care to return `:as` values (otherwise full key-value pairs are returned instead):

```perl
raku -e 'my %h.=append(.words[0] => .words[1..*]) for lines;  %h.classify(*.keys, :as{$_.values}).put;'
```

Run the above on a small dataset, for example, the `warpbreaks` data from the R-programming language (54 rows, 3 columns), the second column of which references two types of wool, "`A`" and "`B`".

- [Input file is as follows: `warpbreaks` dataset exported from `R`
  using     `write.csv` with `row.names=FALSE`, post-processed to
  remove    double-quotes, as well as converting commas to tabs].

Working Raku code (and return), below. Note how non-key  `value`columns can be `join`-ed with `"|"` (or joined using `join(",")`, etc.):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my %h.=append(.words[1] => .words[0,2].join("|") ) for lines.skip(1);  %h.classify(*.keys, :as{$_.values}).put;'  warpbreaks_no_quotes.tsv
A   26|L 30|L 54|L 25|L 70|L 52|L 51|L 26|L 67|L 18|M 21|M 29|M 17|M 12|M 18|M 35|M 30|M 36|M 36|H 21|H 24|H 18|H 10|H 43|H 28|H 15|H 26|H
B   27|L 14|L 29|L 19|L 29|L 31|L 41|L 20|L 44|L 42|M 26|M 19|M 16|M 39|M 28|M 21|M 39|M 29|M 20|H 21|H 24|H 17|H 13|H 15|H 15|H 16|H 28|H
```

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/warpbreaks.html
https://docs.raku.org/routine/classify
https://raku.org

Answer (score 1):

Python module itertools has a method (groupby) which does exactly what you want. You just give it an iteratble (file handle) and a function to group on (lambda aka, anonymous  or inlined function, grouping on first column(x.split()[0])

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for k,igrp in it.groupby(f,lambda x: x.split()[0]):
    print(k,*["".join(e.split()[1:]) for e in igrp])
' file
```

---

Using GNU sed with extended regex mode (-E) we accumulate the consecutive lines having the same first field without printing. Then when a transition occurs, print the first portion, remove it, and cycle repeats

```
sed -E ':a
  $!N
  #  12   2    1       3    3
  s/^((\S+)\s.*)\n\2\s+(\S.*)/\1 \3/;ta
  P;D
' file
```

---

Using awk we set the ORS to empty

```
awk -v ORS= '
NR==1 || prev != $1 {
  if (NR > 1) print RS
  prev=$1;print
  next
}
{ $1="";print }
END { print RS }
' file
```

---

Perl using the ellipsis operator (..) in a scalar context to get a range of lines.

```
perl -lane '$,=$";
  my $e = ($p=$F[0],1) .. ($F[0] ne $p);
  if ($e =~ /E0/) {
    print $p, splice @A;
    $p = $F[0];redo;
  }
  push(@A,splice(@F,1));
  }{print $p, @A;
' file
```

---

Output:-

```
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the associative arrays of awk might be an easier option:

```
$ awk '{k[$1]=k[$1]" "$2} END {for (i in k) print i k[i]}' infile 
a 12 13 15 14
b 5 6
c 2 5
```

Comment: Nice and simple I think