# Need help regarding making multiple columns

Tags: text-processing

I need to convert my data into multiple columns. Input data:

```
a1 n1
a2 n2
a3 n3
.  .
.  .
.  .
an nn
a1 m1
a2 m2
a3 m3
.  .
.  .
.  .
an mn
a1 x1
a2 x2
a3 x3
.  .
.  .
.  .
an xn
a1 y1
a2 y2
a3 y3
.  .
.  .
.  .
an yn
a1 z1
a2 z2
a3 z3
.  .
.  .
.  .
an zn
```

I want to convert the data above into multiple columns. I want my output data to look like this:

```
a1 n1 m1 x1 y1 z1
a2 n2 m2 x2 y2 z2
a3 n3 m3 x3 y3 z3
.  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  . 
.  .  .  .  .  .
an nn mn xn yn zn
```

Please help me in this conversion. I am using Linux.

Thank you.

Comment: What algorithm should we follow? How can we know if something should be on the same line? Are your data actually like this? Should we group by the second character of every field?

Comment: Get rid of the ellipsis to provide sample input/output we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Comment: Related if not duplicate of [Grouping by first column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/686655/grouping-by-first-column).

Answer (score 4):

This is a good case for the use of awk's associative arrays:

```
$ awk  '{a[$1]=a[$1]"   "$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' q763033 
a1    n1   m1   x1   y1   z1
a2    n2   m2   x2   y2   z2
a3    n3   m3   x3   y3   z3
an    nn   mn   xn   yn   zn
```

the input file q763033 is:

```
$ cat q763033
a1 n1
a2 n2
a3 n3
an nn
a1 m1
a2 m2
a3 m3
an mn
a1 x1
a2 x2
a3 x3
an xn
a1 y1
a2 y2
a3 y3
an yn
a1 z1
a2 z2
a3 z3
an zn
```

Comment: If you change `a[$1]=a[$1]"   "$2` to `a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1]"   " : "") $2` or `a[$1]=a[$1] s[$1] $2; s[$1]="  "` then it won't print 2 blank chars at the start of each output line.

Comment: The `for (i in a)` can change the order of the output from the order of the input since the order that `in` visits array indices is undefined, idk if the OP would care about that or not.

Answer (score 2):

Using `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -sW -c $'\t' collapse 2 -g 1 <file
```

Or

```
$ datamash -sW --output-delimiter=' ' -c ' ' collapse 2 -g 1 <file
```

From [`datamash` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/html_node/Invoking-datamash.html#index-_002d_002doutput_002ddelimiter):

> --output-delimiter=x
>
> Use character X instead as output field delimiter. This option overrides `--field-separator/-t/ --whitespace/-W`.

> --collapse-delimiter=x
>
> -c x
>
> Use character X instead of comma to delimit items in a ‘collapse’ or ‘unique’ list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the first field of your space-delimited data is a "key" and the second field is a "value", you may collect all the values for each key using Miller (`mlr`) from the file called `file` like so:

```bash
$ cat file
a1 n1
a2 n2
a3 n3
an nn
a1 m1
a2 m2
a3 m3
an mn
a1 x1
a2 x2
a3 x3
an xn
a1 y1
a2 y2
a3 y3
an yn
a1 z1
a2 z2
a3 z3
an zn
```

```bash
$ mlr --from file --nidx nest -f 2 --ivar space
a1 n1 m1 x1 y1 z1
a2 n2 m2 x2 y2 z2
a3 n3 m3 x3 y3 z3
an nn mn xn yn zn
```

This reads the data as a Unix toolbox formatted file (fields are delimited by spaces and records are delimited by newlines), and then "nests" the data in the second field, creating new records that contain all the values from the second field that share the same first field.  Spaces delimit the nested data, so there's no telling that the first field is one field and the other fields are all another single field.

Converting the output to JSON shows what really is generated:

```bash
$ mlr --from file --n2j nest -f 2 --ivar space
[
{
  "1": "a1",
  "2": "n1 m1 x1 y1 z1"
},
{
  "1": "a2",
  "2": "n2 m2 x2 y2 z2"
},
{
  "1": "a3",
  "2": "n3 m3 x3 y3 z3"
},
{
  "1": "an",
  "2": "nn mn xn yn zn"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my %hash; %hash.push: .split(/ \s+ /); END .kv.put for %hash.sort;'  file
```

Here's an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features high-level support for Unicode (if that's an issue in your datasets).

Using the awk-like `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags, we `BEGIN` by declaring a `%hash` (associative array). In the main body of the code, the two columns are `split` on whitespace and `push`ed onto the `%hash`, which understands the items to be a "key-value" pair. Each new value per known key accumulates, and at the `END` you simply out`put` the `kv` version (regularizes spacing between elements).

Sample Input:

```
a1 n1
a2 n2
a3 n3
an nn
a1 m1
a2 m2
a3 m3
an mn
a1 x1
a2 x2
a3 x3
an xn
a1 y1
a2 y2
a3 y3
an yn
a1 z1
a2 z2
a3 z3
an zn
```

Sample Output (using final statement above):

```
a1 n1 m1 x1 y1 z1
a2 n2 m2 x2 y2 z2
a3 n3 m3 x3 y3 z3
an nn mn xn yn zn
```

Sample Output (using `.say` instead of `.kv.put`):

```
a1 => [n1 m1 x1 y1 z1]
a2 => [n2 m2 x2 y2 z2]
a3 => [n3 m3 x3 y3 z3]
an => [nn mn xn yn zn]
```

---

Finally, you can convert to JSON if so desired:

```
~$ raku -MJSON::Tiny -ne 'BEGIN my %hash; %hash.push: .split(/ \s+ /); END put to-json( %hash );'  file
[ { "a1" : [ "n1", "m1", "x1", "y1", "z1" ] }, { "a2" : [ "n2", "m2", "x2", "y2", "z2" ] }, { "a3" : [ "n3", "m3", "x3", "y3", "z3" ] }, { "an" : [ "nn", "mn", "xn", "yn", "zn" ] } ]
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/hashmap
https://raku.org